# animate imageview along the curve

Tags: android, animation

I have drawn an arc which is basically parabolic in shape.I want an imageview to follow that curve and eventually fall on the ground where the curve ends.Please suggest me android API's which I can use to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please suggest me android API's which I can use to achieve this.

[TranslateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html#TranslateAnimation%28int,%20float,%20int,%20float,%20int,%20float,%20int,%20float%29) to from one point to the other

`RotateAnimation` to rotate the image as it travels along the curve.

`AnimationSet` to combine these two if needed.